# Elasticsearch advanced sorting with if statement

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES I have objects "person", that can look like that:

```
{
 name: "a",
 type: "single"
}


{
 name: "b",
 type: "family",
 children: {
   {
     name: "ba",
     active: 1
   },
   {
     name: "bb",
     active: 0
   }
 }
}

{
 name: "c",
 type: "family",
 children: {
   {
     name: "ba",
     active: 0
   },
   {
     name: "bb",
     active: 0
   }
 }
}
```

Now I would like to get all "person" but ... `if type = family and all children active = 0` then this object should be on the bottom of the list (_score = 0)

How can I get this type of sorting?

Answer (score 1):

You could go about this a couple different ways with similar results:

- [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)
- [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

I think the best approach would be using the **Function Score Query**.  The reason for this is because the boosting (or demoting) portion is kept separate from the query itself.  So if you're allowing users to search by name, for example, then that portion is separate from the part that demotes families that don't have active children.

You'll want to start by updating the mapping for the "children" field as `nested`, which will allow you to work with the individual items contained in the array of children objects.  After that, the right `function_score` query will allow you to demote items that match your criteria.  I'm just spit-balling the field mappings and query you'd need, but hopefully this will help you get started.

**Notional field mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "children" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
            },
            "active": {
              // Unless you intend to do some math with the active
              // field, you should probably us a boolean for this flag
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Notional query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { "match_all": {}},
      // Other options available for boost_mode, e.g. multiply--see docs
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "functions": [
        {
          // You'll need to tweak this weighting, depending on your query
          "weight": 5,
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                // Filters this boost to apply only to `type: family`
                { "term" : { "type" : "family" }}, 
                // Nested query to select items with active children.  
                // Using `score_mode: sum` means that more active children will
                // give more of a boost.  Other score modes available
                {
                  "nested": {  
                    "path" : "children",
                    "score_mode" : "sum",
                    "query" : {
                      "bool" : {
                        "must" : [
                          { "term" : { "children.active" : true }}
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } 
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will apply a boost to the records that have active children, which will leave the rest at the bottom.  Alternatively, you could write a query that only matches records that have no active children, and apply a negative weight.

If you have another question about how to get either of these parts working, just submit another question specific to the issue you're having.  Good luck!